# USB based video capture card with API

Tags: api, video, usb, video-capture

I am looking for a usb based video capture card (to be used with cctv analog cameras) which comes with an api. An api of sorts would help as I am planning to do some analytics on the video stream.

Any ideas on such a device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform? Pretty much any capture card would work with [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407331%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows. On Linux, the usual API is [V4L](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) - the hardware compatibility list isn't as extensive on Linux, but most things do work with it.

Comment: windows xp/7 (either works). So is directshow usually able to attach to any video stream? or does it have to be a supported device?

Comment: Well, Windows provides a standard interface for the driver developer to program against. As long as they've programmed their driver against the standard interface for capture cards, then it'll "just work". I can't imagine why you'd make a capture card that didn't work with DirectShow - that's how Windows Media Center talks to capture cards, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The only capture boards I know of internal to a PC are PCI capture cards. A USB capture card would limit the data you could capture. For instance if you try to stream video to a USB drive you'll get error messages because USB is too slow. You're better off purchasing an encoder to do what you want. Retail for an analog encoder is as low as 300 dollars and it allows you to connect 4 analog cameras.